# How can i install apk within app without getting storage permissions

Tags: android, firebase

Now I can install the application without the play store with the apk that I downloaded from the server but i want to do this without asking for read/write permissions.

In Firebase app tester, we can install apk without obtaining read/write permissions. I want to do the same in my own application, but I couldn't find any working solution. I'm looking for a solution that will support api 19 and above.

Comment: Download the APK to internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()` on `Context`). Use `PackageInstaller` to install it. [Here is a sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/master/AppInstaller/src/main). It is covered in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-pkg-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Q).

Comment: Thanks for your  answer, I'm trying this solution without coroutine because my project using rx java.  Now its not working without coroutine i am researching how to do it with rx java, I'll let you know if there is a solution, thanks. @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried this solution but I am getting "file not found error"  and I couldn't find a solution.   I using this code for apkUrı;                  apkUri = content://com.xxx.xxx.beta.provider/external_files/Download/XXX.apk                                                       Code: val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + PROVIDER_PATH,
            File(destination)
        ).

Comment: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] and the complete stack trace of your error.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I try your solution and it works, but in my case when I install the app it shows "Ask for Update Dialog". But while the update is installing and after it's complete it doesn't show me an update progress dialog or completed dialog but it installs the app in the background, so I fixed this issue using my old solution method and it's working now. @CommonsWare